# Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am encountering this problem yet I have done everything right.

"Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - kotlin.Unit"

my Entity code is this

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
data class Note (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    val name: String,

    val email: String
)
```

An Update. The error was originating from my Dao class
The code was as follows

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY ID ASC")
suspend fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>
```

Comment: Are you creating entity for room db?

Comment: Try give some default values for name and email or try making name and email as nullable. Like name:String?

Comment: The error originated from my Dao class. Specifically, the Query I have posted above. It is rejecting the LiveData return type, yet it has worked on my previous projects

Comment: Try removing the `suspend` keyword from your `getAllNotes()` method.

Comment: In the code you provided for your entity, it looks like you have defined a public constructor with three parameters: id, name, and email. This should be enough to satisfy the requirement that entities and POJOs have a usable public constructor.

It's possible that the error you are encountering is coming from a different part of your code, such as your DAO class. Can you provide the code for your DAO class, along with any other relevant code? That would be helpful in determining what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

As @DarShan mentioned, the suspend keyword in the dao class shouldn't be there. Specifically if the function should return a liveData